# revealing module pattern (javascript) - this cannot access private methods

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, revealing-module-pattern

:I have a javascript class written in the 'revealing module pattern':

```
myObject = function () {
    var varA,
        varB,

        methodA = function (data) {

            //Some code...
        },
        methodB = function (data) {
             var that = this;
             that.methodA("a"); // --> 'that' recognize only public methods: 'methodB' / 'methodC' !!!
        },
        methodC = function (data) {

        };
        return {
            methodB : methodB,
            methodC : methodC,
         };
} ();
```

as you can see in 'this' inside 'methodB' does not recognize private methods of the class.

**Edit:**
My intention was to call a helper private method from a public class. Within this private class I needed 'this'. If I call 'methodA("a")' directly from 'methodB' (without 'that') I do not have 'this' ('this' will be global context). The solution will be:

```
methodA.call(this, "a");
```

Comment: Try giving this article a read. It might give you a better understanding of the pattern: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do here??? And what is the question? Are you trying to do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/qkxzz/1/)?

Comment: In short: memberA is not a key in your object. It's just a variable inside constructor (thus might be called private).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you have error in

```
return {
    methodB = methodB,
    methodC = methodC,
}
```

It should be

```
 return {
    methodB : methodB,
    methodC : methodC
}
```

In your example you have

```
methodB = function (data) {
         var that = this;
         that.methodA("a");
    }
```

`that=this` and the keyword `this` refers to current object and you have returned an object with `methodB`and`methodC` but in your object you don't have`methodA`so `that.methodA("a")`is not working inside`methodB`because`methodA`is not the part of your current object but if you were wrote it like

```
methodB = function (data) {
    methodA("a");
}
```

Then it would have run.

`that=this`and`this=myObject`and `myObject`has only two methods `methodB`and`methodC` so `that.methodA("a")` which means `myObject.methodA("a")` should not run because it doesn't exist in `myObject`

[**DEMO-1**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/k53xv/) and [**DEMO-2**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/ym4Fn/)